# Compare date from textbox with date in database in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, date

I am trying to compare a date I enter in a textbox in a `DD.MM.YYYY` format and I get an error.

```
string txt = "select count(*) from cont where Data_deschiderii < " + Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text).ToString("DD.MM.YYYY");

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(txt, conn);
int x = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
Response.Write(x);
```

How could I do it? I couldn't find ANYTHING on the internet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is to start using prepared, parameterized queries. They ensure that comparisons are done correctly, and they prevent the possibility of SQL injection attacks.

Your code would be rewritten like this:

```
string txt = "select count(*) from cont where Data_deschiderii < @compareDate;"; 
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(txt, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@compareDate", SqlDbType.Date);
cmd.Parameters["@compareDate"].Value = TextBox1.Text;
int x = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
Response.Write(x);
```

That is, I am assuming that your database field `Data_deschiderii` is of a `date` form of datatype.

Comment: Sure, keep in mind the use of parameterized queries for all of your SQL commands. Without them you leave yourself open to SQL Injection attacks. By simply using parameterized queries, you get rid of that attack vector all-together. Plus you get the added benefit of ensuring all of your comparisons are properly typed. It also makes the code a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the date time to something SQL understands.

```
var formattedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

And then use `formattedDate` in your query

Comment: it doesn't work, I get an "incorrect syntax near 00" error

Comment: It's quite possible something else in your query is incorrect. I would check the rest of the query, such as the fields and tables

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the datetime in timespan and then compare that timespan in seconds. In SQL you could convert the same using DateDiff function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
try
{
  DateTime Date1= Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  DateTime Date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  if (Date1 > Date2) 
  {
    Your Code...
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```